# Move inline function from header to source

Tags: c++, inline

I am new to C++ so I apologise in advance for the mundane nature of my question.

I have been asked to move the following inline function from a header file to a source file. However I am struggling to get the syntax right in the source file.
This is the inline function in the header file:

```
class G1FRViewOption
 {
    public:
        enum ViewType {partyView, contraView, unknown} ;
        G1FRViewOption() : m_view     (nullString )
                     , m_viewType (unknown    )
                     , m_isValid  (false      ) {initialise();} 
        G1FRViewOption(const RWCString view) : m_view     (view    )
                                         , m_viewType (unknown )
                                         , m_isValid  (false   ) {initialise();}
        void initialise()
        {
            static RWCString views[] = {"party","contra"} ;
            for (int vt=counterpartyView; vt<unknown; vt++)
                if (m_view.compareTo(views[vt], RWCString::ignoreCase)==0)
                {
                    m_viewType  = (ViewType) vt ;
                    m_isValid   = true          ;
                    break ;
                }
        } 
        RWCString getErrorMessage()
        {
            return "Invalid " + getFieldLabel() + " given. Valid values are party, contra.";
        }
        G1FRViewOption & operator = (const G1FRViewOption & other)
        {
            this->m_view     = other.m_view     ;
            this->m_viewType = other.m_viewType ;
            this->m_isValid  = other.m_isValid  ;
            return *this ;
        } 
              RWBoolean   is        (ViewType viewType) const {return viewType == m_viewType ;} 
              RWBoolean   isValid   () const {return m_isValid ;} 
        const RWCString & toString  ()       {return m_view    ;} 
        static const RWCString       & getFieldLabel         () { static RWCString value = "View"         ; return value ; } 
        static const FieldDefinition & getFieldDefinition    () { static const FieldDefinition fd (getFieldLabel(), 13) ; return fd ; } 
    private:
        RWCString m_view     ;
        ViewType  m_viewType ;
        RWBoolean m_isValid  ;} ;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

C++Newbie!

Comment: That's not a function. That's an entire class.

Comment: What's the question and that's not a function.

Comment: For this kind of basic question, please replace your code with a simple example.  This avoids posting your code and expecting people to read.

Comment: You ask a very simple question yet post a whole load of code. You can illustrate the problem with a five-line example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You move the functions out of the header into a cpp file by first creating the corresponding cpp file if it does not exist, and then copying the bodies of your functions into that file one by one, prefixing their names with the name of the class and two colons `::`, like this:

```
void initialise()
{
    static RWCString views[] = {"party","contra"} ;
    for (int vt=counterpartyView; vt<unknown; vt++)
        if (m_view.compareTo(views[vt], RWCString::ignoreCase)==0)
        {
            m_viewType  = (ViewType) vt ;
            m_isValid   = true          ;
            break ;
        }
}
```

from the header becomes

```
void initialise();
```

in the header, and

```
void G1FRViewOption::initialise()
{
    static RWCString views[] = {"party","contra"} ;
    for (int vt=counterpartyView; vt<unknown; vt++)
        if (m_view.compareTo(views[vt], RWCString::ignoreCase)==0)
        {
            m_viewType  = (ViewType) vt ;
            m_isValid   = true          ;
            break ;
        }
}
```

in the cpp file.